# Time Machine not doing incremental backups any more after unmounting one of my disks once

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a problem with my Time Machine backups. I have two harddrives in my MBP and I unmonted my spinning harddrive once bc I was studying and it was getting annoying. As I knew I would need no files from my 'data partition' I resumed with only my SSD. When I mounted the harddrive again everything was working as before.

But since then my Time Machine is acting up. Whenever I want to backup it says that I dont have enough space and it would require ~660GB of additional space for the backup which accounts for my total amount of backuped data. I only have a 1TB backup volume, but that's more than enough space usually, so I think it is not doing incremental backups anymore.

My hardrive layout consist of my system disk `Macintosh SSD` and my data disk `Macintosh HDD`.

I tried to use tmutil to fix some things. I tried

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Pro/
```

and

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk -a /Volumes/Macintosh\ HDD  /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/MacBook\ Pro/2015-09-09-134637/Macintosh\ HDD
```

but it didnt change anything.
Also when runing tmutil compare it would only show a difference of 8.3GB (last bit of output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NhmZkfM6) instead of the reported 660GB.

[image]

The only reason to move on would be to delete my current backup and start a completely new one, which I don't really want to do as it is my only full backup on the harddrive.

What advice do you have from here?