# Moving Time Machine backup between two local disks results in full backup instead of incremental

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine

## The Problem

---

After migrating the entirety of a a Backups.backupdb to a new hard drive as [recommended by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202380) by simply copy-pasting within Finder between two local disks, Time Machine encountered an interesting issue. Though it successfully used the new disk to backup whilst recognizing the old backups, instead of creating another incremental backup (as expected normally), it instead created a full backup. As a result, the old backups were deleted from the new drive to make room for the full backup (I still have the original drive and all of its data.) This is not the desired result for me, as I would like to keep my old backups.

## Attempted Solutions

---

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206608/time-machine-not-doing-incremental-backups-anymore-after-having-unmounted-one-of) seems to indicate some similar problem, but has no resolution. Using [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) on the new disk per [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58405/time-machine-keeps-doing-full-backups) simply confirms this.

[image]

## Additional Info

---

Running OS X 10.11.4 on an Early 2009 iMac. Original drive is 2TB Western Digital My Book Studio (over Firewire), new drive is 2TB Western Digital My Passport (over USB 2.0.)

## Backup.log edit

---

At the request of @klanomath, I've added the logs for the relevant backups. The first log is that of the last normal backup. The second log is that of an abnormal backup.

```
2016-05-17-00:03:28 - Starting backup

Previous snapshot:
    /Volumes/WD 2TB Drive/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-16-194333

Resuming from partial snapshot:
    /Volumes/WD 2TB Drive/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-17-000323.inProgress/2FA31DEC-3830-444F-909A-23327D33BDA8

Date of Previous snapshot: 1463453013865462

Will use FS events for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 964EFA4E-DBFD-4A1D-BBCF-929A7DFE52D5)
=== Starting backup loop #1 ===
  Will use IncrementalBackupCopier

Running preflight for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 964EFA4E-DBFD-4A1D-BBCF-929A7DFE52D5)
    Scanning nodes needing deep traversal
    Deep event scan at path: / reason:must scan subdirs|new event db|
    Calculating size of changes
    Should copy 1032 items (1.56 GB) representing 380579 blocks of size 4096. 13994642 blocks available.
Preflight complete for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 964EFA4E-DBFD-4A1D-BBCF-929A7DFE52D5)
Time elapsed: 25 minutes, 5.000 seconds

Processing preflight info
    Space needed for this backup: 6.38 GB (1558644 blocks of size 4096)
    Preserving last snapshot /Volumes/WD 2TB Drive/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-16-194333
    Preserving snapshot for resume /Volumes/WD 2TB Drive/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-17-000323.inProgress/2FA31DEC-3830-444F-909A-23327D33BDA8
Finished processing preflight info

Copying items from "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 964EFA4E-DBFD-4A1D-BBCF-929A7DFE52D5)
Finished copying items for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 964EFA4E-DBFD-4A1D-BBCF-929A7DFE52D5)
Time elapsed: 27 minutes, 48.000 seconds
    Copied 10909 items (519.2 MB)
Gathering events since 278311658.

Backup complete.
Total time elapsed: 1 hour, 34 minutes, 56.000 seconds
```

---

```
2016-06-09-23:28:52 - Starting backup

Previous snapshot:
    /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-17-012013

Date of Previous snapshot: 1463473213959891

Will traverse "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 75C53067-E162-4724-A37E-F5758FE3CF9A)
=== Starting backup loop #1 ===
  Will use IncrementalBackupCopier

Running preflight for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 75C53067-E162-4724-A37E-F5758FE3CF9A)
    Scanning nodes needing deep traversal
    Deep event scan at path: / reason:must scan subdirs|require scan|
    Calculating size of changes
    Should copy 2516438 items (654.1 GB) representing 159691863 blocks of size 4096. 123660133 blocks available.
Preflight complete for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 75C53067-E162-4724-A37E-F5758FE3CF9A)
Time elapsed: 1 hour, 36 minutes, 3.000 seconds

Processing preflight info
    Space needed for this backup: 677.62 GB (165433715 blocks of size 4096)
    Preserving last snapshot /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-17-012013
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/51AAC72E-43B3-494C-920F-DBC743CB576B'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-20-005501'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-19-004324'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-27-001208'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-26-005336'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-25-001601'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-24-005919'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-23-000842'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-22-223214'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-04-233459'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-03-182216'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-02-014115'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-01-002154'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-04-30-001703'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-11-010315'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-10-213059'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-09-185626'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-08-001405'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-07-213404'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-15-233919'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-15-222613'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-15-211225'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-15-200112'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-15-122209'
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-05-16-194333'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 107
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2013-11-28-143225'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 106
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2013-12-06-161600'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 105
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2013-12-13-162811'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 104
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-01-04-071328'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 103
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-01-11-094822'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 102
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-01-19-201718'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 101
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-01-26-004459'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 100
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-02-02-224934'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 99
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-02-09-122445'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 98
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-02-16-153017'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 97
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-02-23-110842'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 96
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-03-02-051545'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 95
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-03-09-112734'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 94
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-03-16-211114'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 93
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-03-23-091814'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 92
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-03-30-101105'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 91
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-04-06-134336'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 90
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-04-20-105220'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 89
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-05-04-002407'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 88
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-05-11-000646'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 87
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-05-18-001335'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 86
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-05-25-003018'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 85
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-06-01-001758'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 84
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-06-08-001707'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 83
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-06-15-003328'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 82
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-06-22-000047'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 81
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-06-29-000019'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 80
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-07-06-001756'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 79
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-07-13-153516'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 78
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-07-27-001304'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 77
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-08-06-005309'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 76
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-08-13-120849'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 75
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-08-20-172631'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 74
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-09-03-165519'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 73
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-09-10-084128'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 72
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-09-20-121117'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 71
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-09-27-123158'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 70
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-10-04-132743'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 69
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-10-12-101138'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 68
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-10-19-104224'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 67
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-10-26-172829'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 66
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-11-02-184352'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 65
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-11-09-005516'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 64
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-11-16-002629'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 63
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-11-28-120121'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 62
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-12-06-211411'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 61
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-12-18-000837'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 60
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2014-12-27-172230'
    Needs space for backup. Will delete oldest snapshots. Total snapshot count: 59
    Deleting old snapshot at '/Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2015-01-03-000953'
Finished processing preflight info

Copying items from "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 75C53067-E162-4724-A37E-F5758FE3CF9A)
Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/ca.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/cs.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/da.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/Dutch.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/el.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/en_GB.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/English.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/fi.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/French.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/German.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/hr.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/hu.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/Italian.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/Japanese.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/ko.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/no.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/pl.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/pt.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/pt_PT.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/ro.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/ru.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/sk.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/Spanish.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/sv.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/th.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/tr.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/uk.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/zh_CN.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Error: (-5000) SrcErr:NO Copying /Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized/zh_TW.strings to /Volumes/WD 2TB Passport/Backups.backupdb/JMY1000's iMac/2016-06-09-232852.inProgress/3A84C59B-83BB-469F-8D45-57AA88CFD91B/Macintosh HD/Users/JMY1000/Music/iTunes 10/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized/.localized

Finished copying items for "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk0s2 mount: '/' fsUUID: F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 eventDBUUID: 75C53067-E162-4724-A37E-F5758FE3CF9A)
Time elapsed: 10 hours, 58 minutes, 9.000 seconds
    Copied 2546768 items (633.66 GB)
Gathering events since 528511994.

Backup complete.
Total time elapsed: 13 hours, 21 minutes, 17.000 seconds
```

## Extended Attributes

---

After doing some research, it appears that extended attributes of relevant files are where the keys are held. Though FSEventIDs were indeed the culprit as @klanomath suspected, editing the main FSEvents database isn't enough alone, according to [this Superuser post.](https://superuser.com/questions/342941/time-machine-event-store-uuids-dont-match-for-volume-after-swapping-disk). (I can't quote it here due to character limits.)

However, [looking at the `SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID`s using `xattr -l`](http://earthlingsoft.net/ssp/blog/2008/03/x5_time_machine), they appear to be unique with each backup, regardless weather it's a full backup or not. `SnapshotVolumeLastFSEventID` doesn't seem to have the same format as `SnapshotVolumeFSEventStoreUUID`, instead being a much shorter string of characters. Only `SnapshotVolumeUUID` appears to remain consistent.

Unfortunately, I'm at a loss on how to *cure* this problem. Though I think it might be possible to postpone it, besides adding more space, I'm not sure if there even is a way to prevent it.

Comment: Please publish (here or at pastebin) the ../.Backup.log files of the new full backup and the most recent on your old backup volume. You'll find them in /Volumes/Backup_Vol_name/Backups.backupdb/host_name/YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss/

Comment: @klanomath Sorry this took so long, I deleted the problematic backup to see if the issue would repeat itself–it did. I'm editing the post now.

Comment: I tested your setup in a VM and had no problems at all. I used different names for the two backup volumes though. The different (invisible!) .Backup.log files may reveal an indication.

Comment: So did I, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Hmm if I remember correctly (meanwhile I deleted the 80 GB VM) the fsUUIDs and the eventDBUUIDs should be identical. The fsUUIDs are but the latter not - I'm not sure though. I may have to redo the VM thingy.

Comment: @klanomath Identical between backups? Pretty sure that's not the case, another known good backup is showing the eventDBUUID CC9CF563-B2E4-40B3-8DD7-8C8FD2318183

Comment: I'm just creating a new VM including 2 backup disks - it will take about 60 minutes though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41028/discussion-between-klanomath-and-jmy1000).

Comment: If you use the dd command on the old drive and the new drive (copy everything from former to latter as-is) and make the name of the new drive identical to the name of the old drive, time machine might not notice the physical switch (I think this would work). Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @NoahL Come join the discussion klanomath and I are having, we think it's something having to do with eventUUIDs.

Comment: @klanomath Attempted your solution of replacing `/.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid`, I didn't let the backup complete but it was attempting a full backup. http://i.imgur.com/7KXMcCp.png

Comment: @klanomath fsUUID was F921CC2C-CB28-3302-A000-C67923A67354 in the new backup, but it still was a full backup.

Comment: @klanomath [This post](http://superuser.com/questions/342941/time-machine-event-store-uuids-dont-match-for-volume-after-swapping-disk) looks interesting: perhaps we need to find a way to get the EventUUID to stay the same. It's odd though, since it appears to have done a deep scan with a new EventUUID on the good backup.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution 1:
Instead of following Apple's recommendation of copying the backup in the Finder,  you might want to try to use Disk Utility to [restore](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22250?locale=en_US) the disk to the new disk (if the new disk is completely empty).

Possible solution 2:
Follow [these](https://ilgthegeek.wordpress.com/2015/03/07/os-x-time-machine-backup-hardware-repairs/) instructions to make sure that MAC Address and UUID match.  I have successfully used this solution in a slightly different scenario, namely to change my backup computer identification so I could keep a backup of a certain state of my computer that would not be deleted when old backups are deleted.  It should also work the other way around.

Comment: First isn't really an option right now since the backups aren't the exclusive users of space on the given disks. In addition, though that would probably work, the reason *why* that works and the copy-paste doesn't is something I'd like to isolate so it's not necessary to use the restore function in the future. 

Regarding the second solution, I'll attempt it, but I don't think it's quite as relevant. The fact that 1. It's a local backup, the MAC address shouldn't matter and 2. The issue is different, as the disk is being accessed by the same computer successfully, and simply refusing (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) to back up incrementally.

Comment: Tried it out: unfortunately, said addresses are already correct, and as such, that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Comment: @JMY1000 That's unfortunate. Another possibility might be to tweak the TM preferences `com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`(in `\Library\Preferences\`). There should be a list of all devices and a string with their DeviceUUID. If you only have two disks listed there (the old one and the new one) you might be able with some trial and error to figure out which one belongs to which and then swap their identification strings. You might need to logout-login or even restart before changes are recognized and make sure you make a backup of the file before changing anything.

Comment: Unfortunately the way Time Machine works and where it stores its relevant data is Apple's well kept secret and (as you have realized) there are no good resources for troubleshooting out there. :(

Comment: I'll try that. Yeah, there really isn't much on it–which is why I came here, so there could be something on it!

Comment: @JMY1000 I would try the following:  Turn TM off. Make a backup of said plist. Delete all/any additional backup drives that you can dispense of from the TM preferences. Transfer the backup manually to the new harddrive. From the plist copy the device ID and string to some text file. Then you add the new harddrive as a TimeMachine backup drive but don't make a backup yet.  Then you change the plist and substitute the new IDs for the old ones.  Restart your computer. Turn TM back on.  Keep fingers crossed that it worked. :)

Comment: I may try that, but I'm not sure given that everything you pointed out is right so far.

Comment: Couldn't find anything that had a DeviceUUID, couple of HostUUIDs though.